# Making Windows software accessible to visually impaired people?

Tags: windows, accessibility

What are some ways Windows software can be made more accessible for visually impaired people?

Comment: W8 guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700407.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320914/creating-accessible-ui-components-in-delphi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689006/what-is-the-correct-solution-to-support-iaccesible-interface-for-caret-movement

Comment: Creating Accessible Computer Applications http://www.afb.org/section.aspx?SectionID=57&DocumentID=198

Answer (score 0):

"[How to Make Your Delphi Applications More Accessible](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33642)" is a short article by Marco Zehe. It describes how to design a Delphi application so that it is usable with screen reading software.